# Fixed number of rows In Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I am having tried a access 2007 report with fixed numbers of rows (records) per page. For example, I like to fix total number of records (rows)  to 10 per page while underlying query might have 5 records in some criteria or 15 records in some case. If any idea, please share me.

TIA
ProNek

Comment: Why do you need a blank line?

Comment: I have an app that prints labels for sticking on a file folder. It's a table of history, and when the label is printed the data is filled out for existing history, and prints blank lines for filling it in by hand. So, it's quite justifiable, seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can us a pagebreak with the visible property set to false and then make it visible when a counter reaches the relevant number.

Further information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119075

Answer (score 0):

You can count and insert page break on the report's body (or section) format event. 
This event fires on every record. You can place a pagebreak at the end of the section and make it visible when you need to print on next page.