# Show 4 records per page in Access form

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a small project using access. The access file has a table and I want to build a form which has a background image like this:

[image]

From the table, i want to put the first 4 records into the image in the form of a text box/field. Then the next 4 in the next page and so on.
This is my first form:

[image]

Finally, I want to print out all of the pages. I tried using multiple records form to get 4 records in a page, but it creates another Form2 I am getting all the records from the table in that form and I don't know how I can get just the four I want. The boxes are also immovable somehow. It looks like this:

[image]

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You should use a report rather then a form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you please point me to some relevant source of information? I'm new to Access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401070/fixed-number-of-rows-in-access-report